# Uncaught TypeError underscore-min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am very new to backbone js. now im trying to create a sample program for backbonejs. This is the simple backbone program. but it shows this error constantly..
    the error is **"Uncaught TypeError       underscore-min.js"** i ve tried so many options like re arranging libraries. but its not working.. please help me

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
        <title>
                Sample Backbone Page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "page">

        </div>


    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script> 


<!--        <script src = "/jquery/jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script src = "/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src = "/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script> -->

        <script>
            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                    '':'home'
                }
            });

            var router = new Router();
            router.on('route:home', function(){
                console.log('we have loaded a Backbone Page');
            });
            Backbone.History.Start();
        </script>

    </body>

</html>

..
```

Comment: use a [non minified version of underscore](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore.js) and check which line is throwing the error

Comment: it shows this error..
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
Sample.**
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
underscore.js **
**Failed to load resource Sample.html** Sample.html is my file name.

Comment: i changed the place of the file.. and now it worked.. how is that possible...oh my god.. previously it was inside eclipse workspace.. is there any reason for that??

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, so this line will throw an error:

```
Backbone.History.Start();
```

To fix it, just change it to:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

See more in the docs: http://backbonejs.org/#History-start

Here is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/oWEquYI/1/edit

Comment: when i copy and paste in my chrome browser .. it shows the same error.. Do i have to change any browser settings??

Comment: i changed the place of the file.. and now it worked.. how is that possible...oh my god.. previously it was inside eclipse workspace.. is there any reason for that??